# Как запускают сервер?

Tags: php, python, веб-сервер

Вот примерный код:

```
... 
server->bind(address:port);
server->listener();
```

Непонятно как нужно использовать подобный код для запуска сервера? Как это все работает? Где нужно его запускать? Где `address:port` указывают домен своего сайта? Обязательно нужен выделенный сервер?

Например для запуска сервера на `python` или `reactphp`.

Comment: ну так привязываешься к ip, а не к домену. По домену через dns-сервер (либо через записи в хостах твоего компа если только для себя делать) находят твой ip и делают обращение к твоему серверу

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для запуска слушателя на `PHP` с использованием `ReactPHP` вам нужно:

1. Настроить веб-сервер, например `Nginx`, на проксирование на любой порт (у `ReactPHP` в демо 1337 порт), если требуется много виртуальных хостов
2. Запускаем через консоль (терминал) `php` скрипт (лучше через `screen`)

Все это делается на любой машине с выделенным IP.

Я для нормального использования `ReactPHP` в свое время писал `PPM` сервер, так как в противном случае все запросы обрабатывает 1 `php` скрипт, и может в любой момент отвалится. Но для таких целей еще может подойти запуск через [supervisor](http://supervisord.org).

Answer (score 0):

Запускают такой сервер либо из консоли - либо устанавливают его как системный сервис/демон.

Для запуска сервера на питоне пишут: `python main.py`. Для запуска сервера на `reactphp` пишут: `php main.php`.

Честно говоря, вопрос такой простой, что даже не понятно что именно тут может быть не понятно.